# Getting 404 on iframe_api. Are we being rate limited or is the API actually hosed?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

We're displaying embedded videos using the iFrame API on a page that's hit by selenium-driven automation ~2 times/10 mins. Our tests have started failing because we're getting intermittent 404s from https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api.

This has been going on for two days now. Are we being rate limited here? Or does the problem lie on Youtube's end?

Comment: Related defect?  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6267

Comment: No. The linked issue appears related to a different (and deprecated API).